How to Reduce Photo Resolution/File Size on OnePlus Nord CE3?
I'm using a OnePlus Nord CE3, and while the camera takes amazing high-quality photos, the file sizes are often quite large (usually exceeding 10 MB). I'm looking for a way to reduce the photo resolution or quality so that the file sizes are around 2-3 MB without compromising too much on image clarity.
However, I couldn't find an option in the Camera app settings to lower the resolution or adjust the quality.
Has anyone else faced this issue? Are there any built-in settings I'm missing?

Camera app usually use a very low JPEG compression level. Have you considered using a JPEG recompression/optimization app for minimizing JPEG files.
